# Start build from any branch by webhook from scmmanager

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, webhooks, scmmanager

Task: Jenkins must start build process from the branch (with any name) into which the changes were pushed by push-event hook.
I have a web interface of scm-manager (hg mercurial) and a web interface of Jenkins.

I watched at form for hooks and I do not now which field is required.

[Form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecdmT.jpg)

Adress of job in Jenkins: https://jenkins.mydomain.net/job/folder/job/job_name/

Can you help me? I want to understand what I need to write in empty fields in scm-manager and what I need to set up in Jenkins. 
I will be grateful for any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible :(
Jenkins plugin for scm-manager does not support working with multibranch pipelines.